# Laravel How to pass collection array into x-component element

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-blade

Hi I need help for my project, I tried to make component panel named "x-panel-sum" and I pass a collection array into element "x-panel-sum". But when i call it from my main blade "index.blade" it turns to be weird such as i lose double quote symbol inside my collection

example:

- normally if i put collection directly in my index.blade

```
{{ $buildings }}
```

and it show to be like this:

[{"id":1,"name":"Kantor Pusat"}]

- But when i try to call x-component

```
<x-panel-sum building="{{ $buildings }}"></x-panel-sum>
```

and the result to be like this:

```
[{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Kantor Pusat}]
```

the double quote becomes "&quot", How do i fix this?

Comment: have you tried this way <x-panel-sum building="{!! $buildings !!}"></x-panel-sum>

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a collection to your component like

```
<x-panel-sum :building="$buildings"></x-panel-sum>
```

note the colon before the attribute. This indicates that the parameter is a php variable.